# alternative for self referential macros

Tags: c, debugging, macros

My project debug outputs became too complex for a human to handle, so I've decided Using Tags (or labels) to make grouping and filtering of log messages easier.

I also want to be able to append newer tags where some tags are already defined.

For example, if header file is included in several C files and define a specific tag, I wish to add another optional tags in each C file. I've tried to do so using self referential macros, but it hasn't works since the pre-compiler process the statement only once. any ideas how to do it properly ?

header.h:

```
#define TAGS "aaa"
```

file1.c:

```
#include "header.h"

#ifndef TAGS 
#define TAGS "bbb"
#else
#define TAGS TAGS ", bbb"
#endif

printf(TAGS);
```

file2.c:

```
#ifndef TAGS 
#define TAGS "ccc"
#else
#define TAGS TAGS ", ccc"
#endif


printf(TAGS);
```

In the example above, I would expect to have "aaa bbb" as output from file1 and the "ccc" in the other file.

Comment: Any reason why you can't have `#else #define TAGS_FILE1 TAGS "bbb" #endif`? Too easy?

Comment: @Lundin, the example above is a very simple case meant to describe a broader issue. In my project i have numerous header files that each can potentially define new tag. when i add new file that include some of thos header files, I don't want to bother myself with all other tags, just add new one if needed.

Comment: @Lundin, I'd like to use a single macro (TAGS), because i've wrapped my printing command to use that name in particular. if I follow your way, i need to define macro for each file  --> `#define print_macro printf(TAGS_FILE1 "etc ..");`

Comment: If you use a macro which is local to the file, you guarantee that the macro is valid, or if not, the problem is to be found in the same file. This might be preferable to a "super macro" which creates a tight coupling between every unrelated file in your whole project. Overall, it seems you are just adding lots of needless complexity. "My program is complex that I need vast debug output, which is so complex, that I need macros to organize it, that are so complex that I need to invent my own complex macro language...".

Comment: @Lundin, I read your advise thoroughly... the only case that bother me is when you have file have multiple headers inclusion - each header define different tag. so eventually, after preprocessing, you have multiple definitions of the same macro (TAGS), and you wish to append them into a single string. Any idea how to do so ?